# using $inject syntax with additional constructor arguments

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Looking at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272093/2547709

Using the $inject syntax my controller ends up looking like this:

```
class MyCtrl {

  public static $inject: string[] = ['$scope'];
  constructor($scope){
    // stuff
  }
}
// register the controller
app.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
```

My question is- what happens if I want to pass my own custom arguments to the constructor as well as any injected variables?:

```
class MyCtrl {

  public static $inject: string[] = ['$scope'];
  constructor($scope, customArg){
    // stuff
  }
}
// Now how do I pass customArg in without it complaining?
app.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl(customArg)); // Nope
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, using this syntax, does everything you pass in to the .controller() function have to be registered with angular and so I shouldn't be trying to pass in custom arguments at all? Or can I pass in an arbitrary value/object? And if so how?

Comment: What's an example of something you want to pass? Can you register it with angular using angular.value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> customArg

You cannot pass in custom argument if *angular* is going to call the constructor. You *can* however register other things with Angular e.g. Services,Factories,Values(constants) that *angular* will pass to the controller for you.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1

Comment: Thanks @basarat, I'm a fan of your videos they're really helping me get to grips with how to use typescript idiomatically with something like angular!

Comment: If you're interested, I have a new question up: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844887/extending-angularjs-directives-with-typescript)

Comment: @basarat: A good example is a provider where you abstract the service into a different class. The question is now, do I want to do it? How would you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the answer I don't have enough points to comment.

I have the exact same scenario and here is my situation:

```
export abstract class DataService<T> {

    static $inject = ['$resource'];
    private svc: ng.resource.IResourceClass<ng.resource.IResource<T>>;

    constructor(
        protected $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, url: string
    ) {
        this.svc = <ng.resource.IResourceClass<ng.resource.IResource<T>>>this.$resource(url, { id: '@id' });
    }

    public get(id: number): ng.IPromise<T> {
        return this.svc.get({ id: id }).$promise;
    }

}

export class MyDataService
    extends DataService<IItem> {


   // big problem here!!!
   constructor(
    ) {
        super("/api/items/:id");
    }

}
```

Looks like I would have to repeat the injection on every derived class and also pass in the super... so redundant